# Один поток на action

Tags: c#, многопоточность, asp.net, mvc, async-await

Читал на хабре статью про async/await и наткнулся на следующую строчку:

> Несмотря на то, что в ASP.NET нет выделенного UI потока, код в
>   action-ах контроллеров не может выполняться более чем одним рабочим
>   потоком одновременно.

Исходя из этой строчки у меня возникают вопросы:

1. Зачем так ограничивать `action`?
2. Как это реализовано `внутрях`? `lock` в `ActionInvoker'е`?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы просто не совсем правильно поняли мысль, котору пытался донести автор статьи. Он не пытался сказать, что один конкретный метод Action не может выполняться в нескольких потоках - ведь достаточно очевидно, что это не так.

Если у вас пришел десяток одновременных HTTP-запросов на один и тот же Action - то это Action будет выполняться одновременно в 10 разных потоках. Никаких блокировок там нет.

Автор статьи на хабре имел ввиду, что один конкретный запрос - один конкретный вызов Action для обработки конкретного запроса - будет выполняться одним конкретным рабочим потоком, к которому при этом будет привязан HttpContext этого самого запроса.

Comment: да, я уже понял, что понял не так, но все же "Если у вас пришел десяток одновременных HTTP-запросов на один и тот же Action - то это Action будет выполняться одновременно в 10 разных потоках" - не совсем верно. Есть частный случай при котором action не выполняется, пока не отработает первый - это когда с одного соединения запрашиваются два одинаковых action, и видимо это следует из ограничения http, хотя уверен не могу быть, что причина в этом. Мне кажется это именно то, что имел в виду автор

Comment: @Qutrix Нет в http таких ограничений. Более того, само понятие action - это понятие, существующее в рамках серверного обработчкика mvc. Http абсолютно все равно, вызываете вы через него MVC Action, или качаете gif :) Если вы из браузера отправите два ajax запроса - они будут обработаны сервером параллельно, в разных потоках. Даже если вы вызовите при этом один и тот же Action. Единственный случай, когда asp.net принудительно обрабатывает запросы последовательно - это использование session state.

Comment: Но позвольте Вам привести пример:
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   public string Index()
   {
       var f = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
       Thread.Sleep(10000);
       return f;
   }
}

Если открыть две вкладки с этим action'ом, то разница между их стартами будет минимум 10 секунд. Запустите, если не верите. Какое дать этому объяснение?

Comment: @Qutrix очень простое объяснение - ваш браузер отправляет запросы с абсолютно совпадающим url один за одним. Легко проверить, взять, например, fiddler, и запустить перехват - видно, что браузер даже не пытается отправить следующий запрос, не дождавшись ответа на предыдущий. Но при этом, если вы в фиддлере сделаете replay сразу для пачки запросов - они уйдут на сервер параллельно. Можно и без fiddler-а получить одновременные запросы - добавьте в url любой незначащий параметр, разный в разных табах (?q=1 и ?q=2), ничего не меняя на сервере - и бразуер отправит такие запросы одновременно.

Comment: @Qutrix вот вопрос на enSO на про это поведение в хроме - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119367/chrome-treating-smart-url-and-causing-concurrent-requests-pend-for-each-other.

Comment: Да, все верно, но у меня еще вопрос относительно этого: "будет выполняться одним конкретным рабочим потоком, к которому при этом будет привязан HttpContext этого самого запроса". Что значит "к потоку привязан HttpContext"? Заранее спасибо за мучения со мной

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45555/discussion-between-qutrix-and-pashapash).