# Для чего нужен делегат Action

Tags: c#

Что есть делегат Action и когда нужно его использовать?

Comment: смотрел описание: [Action](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Comment: С другими `Action<T>` и `Func<T>` все понятно, только по этому делегату вопрос?

Comment: @Grundy конечно смотрел , меня интересует именно практическое применение в каких ситуациях его можно применить. И можно ли без него.

Comment: @АндрейNOP да стеме делегатами более менее ясность есть. Интересует только этот делегат.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Делегат [Action](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action?view=netframework-4.7.2) нужно использовать в случае, когда требуется функция, которая

1. Ничего не возвращает
2. Не принимает никаких параметров

Comment: Тогда получается что это эквивалент  void Metod(){}

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch, если посмотришь по ссылке, то это и есть: `public delegate void Action();`

Comment: Получается,что  это всего лишь быстрое создание делегата заданного вида, в том числе как и Action<T> и Func<T>

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch, это скорее: набор _уже созданных делегатов_ которые можно использовать.

Comment: Добавить (да/нет) 3. Action используется в WinForms для управления контролами WinForms из-под thread-ов многозадачности (из разпаралеленых процессов).

Comment: Добавить (да/нет) 4. Action не разрешает (или таки разрешает?) конфликты многопоточности. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/566763/%d0%9e%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0-action когда из распаралеленых процессов хотят менять один обьект, например можно ли дописывать текст контроле Мемо, или можно ли делать запись в файл или базу?

Comment: @nick_n_a, в вопросе по ссылке же не про делегат Action, а просто action как метод контроллера в mvc. Action здесь это просто обычный делегат, соответственно и поведение его точно такое же. Никаких особенностей